# Track down the deleted the records in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Need to track down the records deleted from the tables from a database. Apart from triggers any other way to do it in sql server?

Comment: Restore the latest backup.

Comment: I came to Knew about a feature Change tracking which can track the changes we done. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do this is to restore the database form a backup and compare the tables, I'd probably go with an EXCEPT query:

```
select * from restored_db.table
EXCEPT
select * from current_db.table
```